# How to auto-generate random hex color code in SQL?

Tags: sql

Is it possible to generate random color codes in SQL and at the same time make the color difference far from one another? For example Yellow, Red, Black, Blue, Magenta....and not like Yellow, Bright Yellow, etc. How can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this works

```
SELECT '#' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3), 2) AS Color
```

Comment: Can we do as temporary in select statement instead of inserting?

Comment: @rookie_coder You can just `select round(rand(...)) as color ...` but at that point you're probably better off doing it in whatever language is doing the fetching. It'll be simpler and it will reduce load on the DB server.

Comment: i think now its more easy i using SQL server

Comment: @ViníciusTodesco the code SELECT '#' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3), 2) AS Color have error like so 

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(MAX), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3), 2) AS Color from operation LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 1

Comment: @ViníciusTodesco think my is mysql how can it be done

Comment: @TheBANNED Sorry but i doesn't have a mysql im my machine try this
SELECT Concat('#' ,  DATE_FORMAT (CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3), 2)) AS Color

Comment: @TheBANNED  try this SELECT concat('#',SUBSTRING((lpad(hex(round(rand() * 10000000)),6,0)),-6))